# Which indian bowler makes the best bowling economy record with highest wicket taking on debut?

Tags: icc, statistics, trivia, cricket

In International Cricket Which indian bowler makes the best bowling economy record with highest wicket taking on debut and give the figures.,

Example Format :

Overs-Runs-Wickets-Economy

10-10-5-2.3

Comment: Do you want the figures for players across all matches or just in their debut games? Also, do you want the stats for Tests, Odis or T20s?

Comment: Only on debut...

Comment: In International T20's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, the statistics for each of the formats (Tests/ODIs/T20s) sorted both by wickets taken on debut and best economy.

### 1. ODIs

1. Sorted on [wickets taken](http://is.gd/wjBFvF)
2. Sorted on [economy](http://is.gd/4JUus5)

### 2. T20Is

1. Sorted on [wickets taken](http://is.gd/Qnf0H9)
2. Sorted on [economy](http://is.gd/rWEExG)

### 3. Tests

1. Sorted on [wickets taken](http://is.gd/CA3hr0)
2. Sorted on [economy](http://is.gd/BroXMh)

Comment: For a statistics based question,it's good to provide link in which the answer will be updated, good answer.